# PHP Se sobreescribe la imagen al actualizar

Tags: php, mysqli

Hice el ejercicio de cargar una imagen al servidor y la sube perfectamente con la ruta a la BD, el problema que tengo es al actualizar otro sin modificar el campo de la imagen.

Inicialmente  subo la ruta a la BD y la almacena en la columna 'imagen', la cargo pasandole la sesion con el respectivo indice. **he intentado poner el atributo 'value' al input File  con la ruta de la misma para ver si deja el valor de la imagen anterior pero no funciona**, Al actualizar el usuario sin cargar una imagen, reescribe 'el value' (en blaco)  y en una nueva consulta no trae nada.

este es mi codigo:

```
  <?php

if(isset($_POST))
{
    require_once '../includes/header.php';
    borrarMessages(); // funcion borrar mensajes
    //Asignacion de variables
    $archivo = isset($_FILES['archivo']) ? $_FILES['archivo'] : FALSE;
    $nArchivo = $archivo['name'];
    $tipo= $archivo['type'];

    $nombre = isset($_POST['name']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['name']) : FALSE; //operador ternario : si da true, almcene el valor que llega por post, sino false
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, trim($_POST['email'])) : FALSE;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, trim($_POST['password'])) : FALSE;
    //$pwdencrypt=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost'=>4]);//encriptar la contraseña
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];


    //COMPROBAR SI EL CORREO YA EXISTE
    $sql = "SELECT id, email FROM usuario WHERE email = '$email'";
    $isset_email = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    $isset_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($isset_email);

    //Si el correo del usuario en sesion es igual al que esta en la bd, ó si esta vacio.
    if($isset_user['id'] == $usuario['id'] || empty(isset($isset_user))){

        //comprobacion del tipo imagen
        if($tipo == 'image/png' || $tipo == 'image/jpg' || $tipo == 'image/jpeg' || $tipo == 'image/gif'){
            $ruta = '../assets/img/img-users/'; //asignacion de la ruta de imagenes

            if(!is_dir($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta, 777);     
            }

        move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $ruta.$nArchivo);
        }
        $rutaImagen = $ruta . $nArchivo;

        $query = "UPDATE usuario SET nombre = '$nombre', email = '$email', password = '$password', imagen = '$rutaImagen' WHERE id = $usuario[id];";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

        if($resultado){
            $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre'] = $nombre;
            $_SESSION['usuario']['email']  = $email;
            $_SESSION['usuario']['imagen']  = $rutaImagen;


            $_SESSION['message']= '<p class="text-success"> Actualizacion Completa!</p>';
            header('location: ../index.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['message']= '<p class="text-danger"> No se pudo Actualizar</p>';
     }
```

Este es el HTML

```
 <?php
require_once "../includes/header.php";
//phpinfo();
?>


<div class="container">
<form  action="controller/updateUsuario.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php $usuarios = consultaUsuarios($conexion);

        if(!empty($usuarios)):
            while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuarios)):?>

        <div class="display-3 text-center text-capitalize text-success">actualiza tus datos</div>
        <div class="container-img text-center">
            <div class="display-4 text-success">Actualiza tu foto</div>
                <img src="Hogwarts/<?= $usuario['imagen'] ?>" alt="user" class="img-fluid">


            <div class="custom-file mt-5">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" name="archivo" value="<?= $usuario['imagen'] ?>" lang="es">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">Seleccionar Archivo</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="text-white">Nombre :</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg border border-success" type="text" value="<?= $usuario['nombre'] ?>" name="name" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="text-white">Correo :</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $usuario['email'] ?>" name="email" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="text-white">password :</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $usuario['password'] ?>" name="password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Actualizar</button>
    </form> 
</div>
```

en header.php, llamo a la conexion con la bd, los estilos.

**¿Cómo puedo prsistir la ruta de la imagen para cuando actualize otro campo, no sobreescriba y deje en blanco el atributo 'value' del campo File?**

Gracias.
[image: Imagen al actualizar el campo imagen, e puede ver que la imagen recoje la ruta de la bd y la pone el atributo src src]

> al actualizar el campo imagen, e puede ver que la imagen recoje la ruta de la bd y la pone el atributo src src

[image: Imagen luego de actualizar otro campo sin tocar el input de la img: sobreescribe la ruta de la imagen y la deja en blanco, al cargar la imagen, no la encuentra]

> luego de actualizar otro campo sin tocar el input de la img: sobreescribe la ruta de la imagen y la deja en blanco, al cargar la imagen, no la encuentra

Comment: `UPDATE usuario SET nombre = '$nombre', email = '$email', password = '$password', imagen = '$rutaImagen' WHERE id = $usuario[id];` estás actualizando la ruta de la imagen. ¿Estás totalmente seguro que `$rutaImagen` siempre tiene la ruta de tu imagen?

Comment: Como dices, al ejecutar la query, '$rutaImagen' no siempre es la ruta. hice un var_dump al $query para ver que es lo queestaba pasando a la bd. **Pues al sobreescribir $nArchivo, lo deja en blanco. y en la query solo se visualiza la direccion de la capeta sin el nombre del arcivo.**

Comment: Como yo lo veo tienes dos opciones: antes del update traes la dirección de la imagen, o pones un condicional donde, si no se adjunta imagen, se use otra sentencia donde no se actualice el campo de imagen. Saludos!

Comment: Efectivamente como los planteaste, resulto.! La validacion la hice justo antes del query. 
Valide si $nArchivo recibia algo haga esta query, sino esta otra. Muchas Gracias.